# Undefined behavior sanitizer suppression file: failed to parse suppressions

Tags: clang, sanitizer, ubsan

After compiling an application with clang 3.6 using **-fsanitize=undefined**,
I'm trying to start the instrumented program while using a suppression file to ignore some of the errors:

```
UBSAN_OPTIONS="suppressions=ubsan.supp" ./app.exe
```

The suppression file ubsan.supp contains:

```
signed-integer-overflow:example.c
```

This leads to an error message:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: failed to parse suppressions
```

The same occurs with a gcc 4.9 build.
The only documentation I can find is http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html, which is for clang 3.9, while I use 3.6 (which doesn't have documentation for ubsan included).

Can anyone provide working examples for ubsan suppression files, that work in clang 3.6?

Edit: By browsing the source code of ubsan, I found that the only valid suppression type might be "vptr_check" - dunno which version I was looking at though.
Can anyone confirm that in clang 3.9 more suppression types are available?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't spend the time to find out exactly which suppressions were available in `clang-3.6`, but it appears that in `clang-3.7` only `vptr_check` is available as a suppression. Starting in `clang-3.8`, the suppressions list is [defined](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/b5214093d4c91ed5352d35ee9126665fabfa97fe/lib/ubsan/ubsan_diag.cc#L361) to be the [list](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/release_38/lib/ubsan/ubsan_checks.inc) of checks, plus `vptr_check`. 
 In `clang-3.9` the checks [available](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/release_39/lib/ubsan/ubsan_checks.inc) are:

- "undefined"
- "null"
- "misaligned-pointer-use"
- "alignment"
- "object-size"
- "signed-integer-overflow"
- "unsigned-integer-overflow"
- "integer-divide-by-zero"
- "float-divide-by-zero"
- "shift-base"
- "shift-exponent"
- "bounds"
- "unreachable"
- "return"
- "vla-bound"
- "float-cast-overflow"
- "bool"
- "enum"
- "function"
- "returns-nonnull-attribute"
- "nonnull-attribute"
- "vptr"
- "cfi"
- "vptr_check"

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried it by creating three files, `compile.sh`, `main.cpp` and `suppressions.supp` as shown below.  The `unsigned-integer-overflow` is not a part of `undefined` that's why it needs to be included specifically.  This works on my machine with clang-3.9.

So, I'd guess more suppression types are valid in `clang-3.9`.

```
# compile.sh
set -x 
UBSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=suppressions.supp:print_stacktrace=1 #:help=1
export UBSAN_OPTIONS
clang++-3.9 -g -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow main.cpp
./a.out

// main.cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <bits/stl_tree.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned int k = UINT_MAX;
  k += 1;
  return 0;
}

# suppressions.supp
unsigned-integer-overflow:main.cpp
```